# Adding simple product with custom options to the cart in android using Ksoap2

Tags: android, soap, soapui, ksoap2

I am developing an android application on Soap api. The library i am using to deal with the api is Ksoap2.

To send the data to add Grouped product into cart, I am sending data like this in SoapUI:

```css
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:shoppingCartProductAdd soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <sessionId xsi:type="xsd:string">513922303bd9a731a29ac1ac419bfbfb</sessionId>
         <quoteId xsi:type="xsd:int">716</quoteId>
         <products xsi:type="urn:shoppingCartProductEntityArray" soapenc:arrayType="urn:shoppingCartProductEntity[]">
  <shoppingCartProductEntity>
  <product_id>555</product_id>
  <qty>1</qty>
  <super_group>
  <associativeEntity>
  <key>547</key>
  <value>1</value>
  </associativeEntity>
  </super_group>
  </shoppingCartProductEntity>
         </products>
         <storeId xsi:type="xsd:string">1</storeId>
      </urn:shoppingCartProductAdd>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and using Ksoap2 library,I am sending the data like this:

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.v("onExecute", "Inside On execute");
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartProductAdd");
        request.addProperty("sessionId", "513922303bd9a731a29ac1ac419bfbfb");
        request.addProperty("quoteId","716");
        request.addProperty("storeId","1");

        SoapObject products = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"shoppingCartProductEntity");
        products.addProperty("product_id","555");
        products.addProperty("qty","1");

        SoapObject options = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"super_group");
        SoapObject associativeEntity = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"associativeEntity");

        associativeEntity.addProperty("key","547");
        associativeEntity.addProperty("value","1");
        options.addSoapObject(associativeEntity);

        SoapObject product1 = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"shoppingCartProductEntityArray");
        products.addProperty("super_group",options);
        product1.addProperty("associativeEntity",products);
        request.addProperty("products",product1);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = false;
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 30000);

        try {
            Log.v("DebuggingCount", "1");
            transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
            Log.v("DebuggingCount", "2");

            object = soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
            Log.v("ObjectBodyIn", "" + object);

            if (object instanceof SoapObject) {
                SoapObject soapObject = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
                Log.v("SoapObjectBodyIn", "" + soapObject);

                SoapObject resultString = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
                Log.v("asddsffg",""+resultString);

                } else if (object instanceof SoapFault) {

                if (((SoapFault) object).faultcode.equals("5")) {
                } else if (((SoapFault) object).faultcode.equals("4")) {
                } else if (((SoapFault) object).faultcode.equals("3")) {
                } else if (((SoapFault) object).faultcode.equals("2")) {
                } else if (((SoapFault) object).faultcode.equals("1")) {
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e1) {
            Log.v("SocketTimeOut", "Inside STO");
        } catch (ConnectException ce) {
            Log.v("ConnectSocket", "Inside CT");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("ExceptionOccured: ", "" + e.getMessage());
            Log.v("ExceptionOccured: ", "" + e.getClass());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And the result is coming true, but when I am adding simple products with custom options using SoapUI, I am sending like this:

```css
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:shoppingCartProductAdd soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <sessionId xsi:type="xsd:string">513922303bd9a731a29ac1ac419bfbfb</sessionId>
         <quoteId xsi:type="xsd:int">716</quoteId>
         <products xsi:type="urn:shoppingCartProductEntityArray" soapenc:arrayType="urn:shoppingCartProductEntity[]">
  <shoppingCartProductEntity>
  <product_id>908</product_id>
  <qty>1</qty>
  <options>
  <associativeEntity>
  <key>68</key>
  <value>Apple</value>
  </associativeEntity>
  </options>
  </shoppingCartProductEntity>
         </products>
         <storeId xsi:type="xsd:string">1</storeId>
      </urn:shoppingCartProductAdd>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And the result is coming true. but the main problem is when i am sending the same data using Ksoap2 library, I am getting faultCode: 1022 and faultstring: 'Please specify the product required option(s). My code to send simple product with custom option is like this:

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.v("onExecute", "Inside On execute");
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartProductAdd");
        request.addProperty("sessionId", "513922303bd9a731a29ac1ac419bfbfb");
        request.addProperty("quoteId","716");
        request.addProperty("storeId","1");

        SoapObject products = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"shoppingCartProductEntity");
        products.addProperty("product_id","908");
        products.addProperty("qty","1");

        SoapObject options = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"options");
        SoapObject associativeEntity = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"associativeEntity");

        associativeEntity.addProperty("key","68");
        associativeEntity.addProperty("value","shubham");
        options.addSoapObject(associativeEntity);

        SoapObject product1 = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"shoppingCartProductEntityArray");
        products.addProperty("options",options);
        product1.addProperty("associativeEntity",products);
        request.addProperty("products",product1);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = false;
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 30000);

        try {
            Log.v("DebuggingCount", "1");
            transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
            Log.v("DebuggingCount", "2");

            object = soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
            Log.v("ObjectBodyIn", "" + object);

            if (object instanceof SoapObject) {
                SoapObject soapObject = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
                Log.v("SoapObjectBodyIn", "" + soapObject);

                SoapObject resultString = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
                Log.v("asddsffg",""+resultString);

                } else if (object instanceof SoapFault) {

                if (((SoapFault) object).faultcode.equals("5")) {
                } else if (((SoapFault) object).faultcode.equals("4")) {
                } else if (((SoapFault) object).faultcode.equals("3")) {
                } else if (((SoapFault) object).faultcode.equals("2")) {
                } else if (((SoapFault) object).faultcode.equals("1")) {
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e1) {
            Log.v("SocketTimeOut", "Inside STO");
        } catch (ConnectException ce) {
            Log.v("ConnectSocket", "Inside CT");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("ExceptionOccured: ", "" + e.getMessage());
            Log.v("ExceptionOccured: ", "" + e.getClass());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

68 is required are in database.

Please help, today I tried to find out what's wrong and got nothing. i wasted my whole day.